# How to map System.Version as Complex Type in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a System.Version object in one of my POCO entities using a Code First Entity Framework 6 application. I'd like to map it to the database as:

```
table Diagnostics
  column ApplicationVersionMajor int
  column ApplicationVersionMinor int
  column ApplicationVersionBuild int
  column ApplicationVersionRevision int
```

How do I do that when the class is something like:

```
class Diagnostics 
{
  public System.Version ApplicationVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can decorate my own value objects with a [ComplexType] attribute; I just don't know how I would do this for a framework type.

Comment: I don't think you can - you _could_ create your own complex type that maps easily to/from `Version`.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about doing that but didn't want to miss some obvious feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since System.Version is a class it can be a complex type.
You can mark it as a complex type with fluent interface.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<System.Version>();
}
```